# Sign data in node js and verify it in Java

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, cryptography

I'm creating the keys pair with [crypto](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) in nodejs.

```
var { publicKey, privateKey } = generateKeyPairSync('rsa', {
        modulusLength: 1024,
        publicKeyEncoding: {
          type: 'spki',
          format: 'pem'
        },
        privateKeyEncoding: {
          type: 'pkcs8',
          format: 'pem',
          cipher: 'aes-256-cbc',
          passphrase: ''
        }
      });
```

The publicKey generated is:

`"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDCnwiV6Opd+3TZf9N1z9GVhxtY\nnqWiFRIsqUOR/vXXge8hbhgm5ITKfZtvyO92Lk+5Tl1Qdrb+OfNcKmBHkGUEdBib\nXCNEXj7SOhQTBH0PnV++8+xJXoutsiJU9Z+sjMCFivbd5wgBizXcY8U9SQfYb+Iv\nNQ8FBL4nV8lMiwAp8QIDAQAB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n"`

I'm trying to sign a message and verify it in Java.

The problem I'm having is to parse the string key (sign key) to `PublicKey` in Java with:

```
public static PublicKey loadPublicKey(String stored) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        byte[] data = Base64.getDecoder().decode((stored.getBytes()));
        X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(data);
        KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        return fact.generatePublic(spec);
    }
```

The error shown is :

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character a`

How can I verify the message?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Remove BEGIN and END lines from your string as these are not valid base64 characters before parsing the base64 which is in between of them.

Comment: I tried but that not works.

Comment: Also replace all `\n`(line breaks) signs with nothing.

Comment: I tried ```.replace("\\n", "")``` and it works. Thank you @michalk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should remove first and second line of your input `String` as these are not part of base64 DER encoded public key. And also remove all line breaks `\n`. Given input String you provided you can solve it like this :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        String pemString = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDCnwiV6Opd+3TZf9N1z9GVhxtY\nnqWiFRIsqUOR/vXXge8hbhgm5ITKfZtvyO92Lk+5Tl1Qdrb+OfNcKmBHkGUEdBib\nXCNEXj7SOhQTBH0PnV++8+xJXoutsiJU9Z+sjMCFivbd5wgBizXcY8U9SQfYb+Iv\nNQ8FBL4nV8lMiwAp8QIDAQAB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n";
        String base64 = toBase64DER(pemString);
        PublicKey publicKey = loadPublicKey(base64);
}

public static PublicKey loadPublicKey(String stored) throws GeneralSecurityException {
        byte[] data = Base64.getDecoder().decode(stored.getBytes());
        X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(data);
        KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        return fact.generatePublic(spec);
}

public static String toBase64DER(String pem) {
    return pem.substring(0, pem.lastIndexOf("\n")) //remove last \n
            .substring(pem.indexOf('\n') + 1) //remove first line
            .substring(0, pem.lastIndexOf("\n") + 1) //remove last line
            .replace("\n", ""); // remove all \n occurences
}
```

For more generic method of preparing base64 input for your method you could also use something like :

```
private static final String BEGIN = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----";
private static final String END = "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";

public static String toBase64DER(String pem) {
        return pem.replace("\n", "") //remove all line breaks \n
                .replace(BEGIN, "") // remove beginning of PEM
                .replace(END, ""); //remove ending of PEM
}
```

and for veryfing the signature :

```
Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA"); // place algorithm name here
signature.initVerify(publicKey); //add public key
signature.update("signedMessage".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)); //set signed data
boolean verified = signature.verify("signatureBytes".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)); //verify signature match
```